# Ctrl + A (select all Text) not working in input using JQGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using JQgrid in my Web Application using demos from http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

However i made it's cell editable on double click overriding ondblClickRow:

```
ondblClickRow: function(){
    var row_id = $("#grid").getGridParam('selrow');
    jQuery('#grid').editRow(row_id, true);
}
```

in my JQgrid config

After double click I can use the input box to edit the values in the cell,
I can use ctrl + C , ctrl + X, ctrl + Z, ctrl + V for copying, cutting undoing and pasting respectively,

**but cannot use ctrl + A for selecting all text in the input box.**
when I press ctrl + A nothing happens with this key combination

**EDIT:**

I figured out that If I remove the 'sortableRows' property i am able to select all text using ctrl + A in my Grid

Following is the JSFiddle Demo for what I am doing:

http://jsfiddle.net/CzVVK/2452/

You can check that by removing 'sortableRows' from the code (Last line in JSFiddle javascript portion)

Sortable rows is a requirement for this application I can't give up that feature.

Any help regarding this will be greatly appreciated